# Replace an xml nodes by using xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt

In this xml, I want to replace the `<transfom>` node with another node `<message>` but copy the data.

Is it possible with xslt, I have used xslt 2.0 to covert the transform node to message node, but it only works for only one flow node.

```
<root
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/something">
    <flow>
        <list name="listName"/>
        <router name="router"/>
        <!-- I have some other tags here -->
    </flow>
    <flow>
        <list name="listName"/>
        <console name="console"/>
        <!-- I have some other tags here -->
    </flow>
    <flow>
        <payload name="example"/>
        <transform name="transform">
            <!-- Some DATA here --->
        </transform>
        <!-- I have some other tags here -->
    </flow>
    <flow>
        <payload name="sada"/>
        <transform name="transform1">
            <!-- Some DATA here --->
        </transform>
        <!-- I have some other tags here -->
        <transform name="transform2">
            <!-- Some DATA here --->
        </transform>
    </flow>
</root>
```

The `<transform>` nodes are present in two `<flow>` nodes. Is there any way to write a generic XSLT, to replace the `<transform>` with `<message>` node maintaining the position of the nodes and the data inside the nodes.

I have used `<xsl:for-each>` and `<xsl:when>` and xpath expressions such as preceding, following. But they only convert `<transform name="transform node">`, but copies all the other xml nodes as is. Please let me know how to resolve this!

---

**Update**

This is the stylesheet I have used for transforming the xml

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="flow">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="descendant-or-self::transform">
                    <message>
                        <xsl:attribute name="doc:name">
                            <xsl:value-of
                                        select="//transform/@name" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <ee:message>
                            <ee:set-payload>
                                <xsl:value-of select="payload" />
                            </ee:set-payload>
                        </ee:message>
                    </ee:transform>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update 14/04/2019**

How to change the namespaces from the `<root>` tag? I have bunch of namespaces to change when transforming. How to do that?

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have added  the stylesheet I did in the question. I'm quite new to xslt, I had experience using xsl:fo for converting xmls to pdf, but not xml to xml, and I'm new to XPath too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation design should be to start with the identity transformation (see section "Example: Identity Transformation" in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-copy) and then only add templates for the nodes you want to transform, in XSLT 3 you can declare the identity transformation as the default processing using `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#built-in-templates-shallow-copy) and then you just have to write a template for the `transform` elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.example.com/something"
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/something"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="flow/transform">
      <message>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
      </message>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpw

in XSLT 2 you have to spell it out:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.example.com/something"
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/something"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="flow/transform">
      <message>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
      </message>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry but a don't see the benefits from ussing a sequence instead of a node-set, other that transforming a perfectly backward compatible stylesheet into an XSLT 2.0+ only stylesheet.

Comment: Given that the question explicitly mentioned XSLT 2 and I had to use `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.example.com/something"` anyway I don't see why backwards compatible matters.

Comment: Sorry, but `xpath-default-namespace` it's also not needed. I want to emphasize that overwriting the identity rule is a basic transformation design, thus the new `xsl:mode` instruction was introduced as you had well answered.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Can you tell me, how to change the namespaces from the root. In the post I have only give one, but in my xml, I have more than 5 namespaces, along with xsl:schemaLocation.

Comment: @BhavaniChandra, you will need to ask a new, separate question where you provide minimal but complete details of the XML input you have and the transformation result you want, together with the code you have, to demonstrate which issue you have.